# How to solve this differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Number 65 in http://www.math.ucsb.edu/mathclub/GRE/GRE8767.pdf asks to find the graphs possible curves that satisfy the differential equation

$(\frac{dy}{dx})^2 + 2y \frac{dy}{dx} + y^2 = 0$

What method is used to solve this differential equation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The given equation can be rewritten as:
$$
\left( \frac{dy}{dx} + y \right)^2 = 0.
$$

You should be able to go from here, assuming you know how to solve [first order linear differential equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#First_order_equation). I don't want to spoil the fun too much! :-)

Comment: Why community wiki? Why not accept credit where credit is due?

Comment: @Gerry The official reason is that it seemed too simple (plus, I didn't want to give out the full answer). For the actual reason, please take a look at my reputation points. I am trying to enjoy it while it lasts. :-)

Comment: Well, but the more credit you accept, the quicker you'll get to 6666.

Comment: @Gerry I see your point. In fact, after writing that comment, I felt guilty of being frivolous, so I wrote an answer to some other question so that I could 'move on' :). Thanks for the push anyway.